# How to get value from JSON in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, api, dart

I am trying to append some fake data to Listview.builder for category display, but i don't want get data from API, so i just create my own json in dart

```
final category = {
          "Table": "Category",
          "Result": [
            {"Name": "Pants", "id": 1, "image": "cat1.png"},
            {"Name": "T Shirts", "id": 2, "image": "cat2.png"},
            {"Name": "Watches", "id": 3, "image": "cat3.png"}
          ]
  };
```

I have create two classes also

```
class CategoryList {
  String table;
  ResultCategory result;

  CategoryList(this.table, this.result);
}

class ResultCategory {
  String name;
  String id;
  String image;

  ResultCategory(this.name, this.id, this.image);
}
```

So my question is how to append this data to Listview.builder

What i have done is

```
Future<List<CategoryList>> _getCategory() async {
    final category = {
      "Table": "Category",
      "Result": [
        {"Name": "Pants", "id": 1, "image": "cat1.png"},
        {"Name": "T Shirts", "id": 2, "image": "cat2.png"},
        {"Name": "Watches", "id": 3, "image": "cat3.png"}
      ]
    };


    Map<String, dynamic> caregoryRes = json.decode(category);

    List<CategoryList> categorys = [];
    CategoryList categoryList =  CategoryList(category.Table, category["Result"]);

    categorys.add(categoryList);

    return categorys;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are try passing  `category["Result"]`
that is list of data about `ResultCategory` to `CategoryList`'s constructor, but `CategoryList`'s `result` property is just a single `ResultCategory` type. I think it would be better to change the class structure first

Answer (score 0):

To load and display data you have to use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: _getCategory(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(itemCount: snapshot.data.length, itemBuilder: ...,);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error');
        } else {
            return Text('Loading');
        }
     }
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Model Class Here

```
    class CategoryList {
  String? table;
  List<Result>? result;

  CategoryList({this.table, this.result});

  CategoryList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    table = json['Table'];
    if (json['Result'] != null) {
      result = <Result>[];
      json['Result'].forEach((v) {
        result!.add(new Result.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['Table'] = this.table;
    if (this.result != null) {
      data['Result'] = this.result!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Result {
  String? name;
  int? id;
  String? image;

  Result({this.name, this.id, this.image});

  Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['Name'];
    id = json['id'];
    image = json['image'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['Name'] = this.name;
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Show Data Screen

```
    class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  Future<CategoryList> _getCategory() async {
    try{
      final category = {
        "Table": "Category",
        "Result": [
          {"Name": "Pants", "id": 1, "image": "cat1.png"},
          {"Name": "T Shirts", "id": 2, "image": "cat2.png"},
          {"Name": "Watches", "id": 3, "image": "cat3.png"}
        ]
      };
      final encodedData = jsonEncode(category);
      final caregoryRes = json.decode(encodedData);
      final data = CategoryList.fromJson(caregoryRes);
      CategoryList categoryList =
          CategoryList(table: data.table, result: data.result);
      return categoryList;
    }finally{
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<CategoryList>(
          future: _getCategory(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data?.result?.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                        title: Text(snapshot.data?.result?[index].name ?? ""),
                      ));
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text('Error');
            } else {
              return Text('Loading');
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Result
[image]

Comment: You copy-pasted FutureBuilder solution from prev answers

Comment: I'm describe all details about integration like model and convert data and show data